# SAML With ping identity getting error invalid issuer

Tags: saml-2.0

I have tried using the sso url as mentioned "Single Signon Service"https://auth.pingone.asia/{env}/saml20/idp/sso , and issuer as [https://auth.pingone.asia/{env}](https://auth.pingone.asia/%7Benv%7D). but getting ErrorCode: INVALID_ISSUER - Unable to find application for spEntityId: 'https://auth.pingone.asia/{env}' in environment {env}.

Please help me to understand where exactly I have wrong configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have created a SAML Application, if not, try creating it with https://apidocs.pingidentity.com/pingone/platform/v1/api/#post-create-application-saml-protocol

*Note: acs url is the place where you want PingIdentity to redirect after login authentication is completed. You will get a SAMLRespose also posted there.*

(OR) You can create SAML application directly from the PingIdentity console itself by selecting Add Application, Select SAML as type, and Set Manual Saml configuration by specifying entity id (something unique) and ACS url.

2. Go to ping console dashboard, and **check the Entity ID of the application, it should match with your AuthnRequest saml:Issuer**

*Example if your dashboard is like this with Entity ID "test",*
[image]

*then your AuthnRequest should look like this:*

```
 <samlp:AuthnRequest
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
        xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
        ID="test"
        Version="2.0"
        IssueInstant="2022-09-19T16:46:59">
        <saml:Issuer>test</saml:Issuer>
      </samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Note the line: **<saml:Issuer>test</saml:Issuer>**